# Excel Formula for Duplicates

Tags: excel, count, duplicates, excel-formula

I'm attempting to code a clever duplicate excel formula, but can't seem to determine how. I have a large list of numbers (172,250 to be exact). I need to find which are duplicates and which are not. I have tried `COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, and SUMPRODUCT,` but all behave very slowly, so much so that it is a hindrance more than a help. What I need is a way to determine a duplicate that will stop after the second is found. I don't need a full count. I'm trying to avoid using VBA as this will eventually be given to an end user, who would be better suited to just copy-pasting the formula into her cells. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell what kind of output you want from the formula, but the Match function will stop at the first duplicate

Comment: If you can sort your list of numbers, that's easy. Or use a PivotTable with Row Labels as the numbers, and a count in the Values box on the numbers themselves.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Match seems like a good idea; however, I'd need a way to better refine the match. EX: A1 has value 256145. If I =MATCH(A1,A:A) I get 1. That doesn't indicate duplicate. However if I =MATCH(A1,A2:A172000) then when I get to =MATCH(A4,A5:A172000) it won't include A1:A3 in the match search.

Comment: @Jerry I can sort. How does that make it easy? Please explain your solution with sorting.

Comment: @steventnorris If A4 were to be found in A1:A3, you would have already flagged it. As I wrote, it's hard to tell what will work for you without knowing the nature of the output you desire.

Comment: What about using Conditional Formatting, set a cell fill color then filter by Cell Number for that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can sort, you can use a simple `=` comparator.

Let's say your numbers are from `A2:A172251` and sorted (leaving one row above for filtering). In B2, put:

```
=A2=A1
```

And drag down. You will get TRUE for duplicates and FALSE for the first occurrence of a number. So if you have the following first column, you get the following second column:

```
Numbers  Duplicates
1        FALSE
2        FALSE
2        TRUE
2        TRUE
3        FALSE
4        FALSE
```

Comment: This works with a slight variation. Using =OR(A2=A1,A2=A3) I can get a result for all duplicates (first row is headers in this case, so no issue there).

Comment: @steventnorris Yes, if you want to get even the first occurrence of a duplicate, that's what I would have recommended as modification.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to sort, and want to return something for EACH duplicate, no matter where in the list, you could do something like:

```
A1:   =ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,$A2:$A$10000,0))
A2:   =OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,$A3:$A$10000,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,$A$1:A1,0)))
```

Select A2 and fill down as far as needed.  Will return TRUE or FALSE depending on if there are duplicates.